# How to add a Images in article page in Joomla?

Tags: joomla3.0

I am trying to add images to my Joomla article page. They do not display. Only the path is showed, like the following

`{gallery}hotel/Al-Bandary-Tower{/gallery}`

Please help me to find out the reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to `Extensions` -> `Plugin Manager` and make sure that `Simple Image Gallery` that you use is turned on. Click on it to open settings.

2) You should have a name of root images directory - directory above "Hotel" in your case - under `Images root`.

3) In the very end of the settings check that `GD library is supported by the server`. Otherwise, ask your hoster to turn it on for your account.

4) In the `details` panel set the radiobutton to "Enabled". Save the settings.

[(source)](http://www.bretteleben.de/lang-en/joomla/very-simple-image-gallery/-anleitung-plugin.html)

If you use K2, note that you can use Simple Image Gallery tags only in [K2's introtext or fulltext blocks](http://www.joomlaworks.net/support/docs/simple-image-gallery).